# How to add custom property to WPF DataGridColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I want to create custom class that inherits from DataGridColumn and add custom property to it. Than I want to create class that inherits DataGrid which will always use this custom column types.
For example: If user adds DataGridTextColumn it should have custom properties available.

I managed to inherit from DataGridColumn and use that class later, but I don't know how to make that column type default (base) for any column my custom DataGrid will use.

I am using C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

Thanks in advance,

Valentino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to download the WPF Toolkit - http://wpf.codeplex.com/. I upgraded the projects to .NET 4 and made my modifications there.

Otherwise if you can't just inherit from DataGridColumn, then have a look at AttachedProperties in WPF.

Comment: I can inherit from DataGridColumn but then I don't know how to implement that class into my custom DataGrid class. My goal is to use custom DataGrid with custom columns.

Comment: I looked at AttachedProperties like you suggested but I didn't understand it. Can you give me a small example with DataGrid and DataGridColumn? I am new to WPF, still getting used to it...

Comment: I made it with attached properties. Thanks